# Why $n$-$n$ and $p$-$p$ interaction do not exist just like $n$-$p$ interaction in a deutron?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why n-n and p-p interaction do not exist just like a bound n-p system i.e. a deutron?

Comment: The interactions occur, but neither are bound. What exactly are you asking about - why they are not bound? Standard intro nuclear physics textbooks discuss this.

Comment: @Jon Custer This is a good question. I am also looking for why they cannot exist. One of the reasons is Pauli exclusion principle but apart from it. I don't have any idea.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147499/ has some info as does https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78107/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the dineutron and diproton unbound?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147499/)

Answer (score 0):

Interactions of particles always exist, and the question is really asking why there are no bound states of nn and pp.

To get a bound state there has to be an effective potential where in order for the particles to be free energy must be supplied. In the np there is an effective attractive potential due to the spill over strong interaction, [called a residual strong force,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) that attracts the two nucleons and forms a bound state.The energy of the system is such that the mass of the deuteron is smaller than the mass of the proton+neutron, due to special relativity algebra, and the neutron cannot decay, so a stable nucleus exists.

In the case of proton-proton the repulsion of the coulomb potential is such  that [the  system is very unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_helium#Helium-2_(diproton)), that is what "negative binding energy" means:

> Helium-2 is an extremely unstable isotope of helium. Its nucleus, a diproton, consists of two protons with no neutrons. According to theoretical calculations, it would have been much more stable (although still undergoing β+ decay to deuterium) if the strong force had been 2% greater. Its instability is due to spin–spin interactions in the nuclear force, and the Pauli exclusion principle, which forces the two protons to have anti-aligned spins and gives the diproton a negative binding energy.

In the [case of nn ,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium#Properties) the neutrons can decay and their being neutral makes experiments difficult. It is assumed they cannot  form bound states, only resonances in scattering or decay of larger nuclei.

The existence of a resonance is measured
[There is a paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1512/1512.00314.pdf) when a dineutron with a binding energy  of the dineutron to the nucleus it comes from, is measured

> A bonded dineutron emission with the
> binding  energy  (Bdn)  within  limitations  1.3  MeV  <  Bdn  <  2.8  MeV

There are Quantum Mechanical models that can show why there are bound and not bound dinucleon states not using the Pauli exclusion .

See this [for example .](https://www.hep.princeton.edu/%7Emcdonald/examples/dineutron.pdf)

> Show that the isospin structure of the interaction matrix element implies that the
> isosinglet deuteron is bound while the isotriplet, (pp, np, nn), is not.

Comment: Why diproton has negative binding energy?

Comment: "spin–spin interactions in the nuclear force, and the Pauli exclusion principle, which forces the two protons to have anti-aligned spins"  these processes  , handwaving, 'push the two protons apart", and it needs energy to overcome their effect. That is why the diproton is seen in reaction products of heavy nuclei.