# Is there a physically meaningful example of a spacetime scalar potential?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, potential

From Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, page 115.

> #### 0-Form or Scalar, $f$
>
> An example in the context of 3-space and Newtonian physics is temperature $T\left(x,y,z\right),$ and in the context of spacetime, a scalar potential, $\phi\left(t,x,y,z\right).$

I'm trying to think of an example of such a scalar potential. Is there one?  Electrostatic potential is the time component of the electromagnetic 4-vector potential, so it's really a vector with 0-valued space components.

Comment: Scalar potentials play a crucial role in nuclear physics.  See my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288357/why-is-nuclear-force-spin-dependent/288499#288499 and here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292913/why-is-the-density-of-the-fermi-gas-in-a-neutron-star-not-changing-the-potential/293523#293523

Answer (score 9):

Within the Standard Model, the simplest model of the Higgs field is a multiplet of Lorentz scalar fields.  This multiplet does have  a non-trivial transformation under an underlying gauge group of the Standard Model;  but under Lorentz transformations, the Higgs field is invariant, as all good Lorentz scalars should be.

Of course, the Higgs field is not a "potential" in the sense that a "potential" is a field whose derivative is a physically observable field;  so if you're strictly looking for a scalar *potential* this isn't what you're looking for.  But to the best of my knowledge it is the only fundamental scalar field we know to date.

Comment: This answer is not entirely in my field of expertise, so if I've garbled anything above, feel free to send me corrections, amendments, and execrations.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a vector or tensor field, then you can get a scalar field by contraction.

Examples:

$J^\mu$ = 4-flux of some quantity. Scalar field: $\rho = \sqrt{J^\mu J_\mu}/c$. Interpretation: proper density.

$k^\mu$ = 4-wave vector; $x^\mu$ = 4-position. Scalar field: $\phi = k^\mu x_\mu$. Interpretation: phase of a plane wave.

Electromagnetic field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$. Scalar fields: $F^\mu_\mu$ and $F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu \nu}$ and $F^{\mu \nu} \tilde{F}_{\mu \nu}$. The first of these is zero, the second is $2(E^2 - c^2 B^2)/c^2$ and the third is $4 {\bf E} \cdot {\bf B}$.

The above are scalar fields, though not normally called 'potentials' because their gradient does not relate to a force. However we can introduce a potential which is by definition a scalar invariant, and then consider the gradient to be a 4-force. We thus obtain
$$
f^\mu = - \partial^\mu \phi.
$$
Such a 4-force is not the electromagnetic force, but it can be used to construct simple models of the strong force.

Comment: Why should we consider those to be potentials?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I may have misunderstood your question, but since you mentioned temperature I thought you were just thinking of anything scalar and invariant and a continuous field. I modified the answer a bit.

Comment: I didn't ask the question well.  I should have specified "classical physics".  And even excluded variational dynamics.  I figure there must be some way of concocting a Lagrangian with a 4-potential that is "physically meaningful".  But, IMO, that is a different mathematical space, which is "less real" than the mathematical space of classical general relativity.  I wasn't even considering QFT.  And since I haven't looked at QFT for quite some time, I'm not in a position to assess any of the answers involving it.  It may be a year or more before I am prepared to accept an answer.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton The added remark I made about strong force but construed either as a classical force or as a contribution to a quantum field.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things one can mean by a potential.

The first is in the sense of a gauge field whose derivatives (in some combination) give the field-strength tensor. For example, the electromagnetic potential $A^\mu(t,\vec{x})$ as you mention. One can certainly write down a theory with a scalar gauge field $B(t,\vec{x})$, however, such a gauge field does not appear in the standard model of particle physics. But, there is nothing wrong with writing down such a theory. See, for example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7334) where the $U(1)$ symmetry is gauged using a scalar gauge field.

The second is in the sense of the potential terms, i.e., the interaction/self-interaction terms in the Lagrangian density. For example, we say things like "the shape of the Higgs potential looks like the logo of a famous StackExchange site". All such potential terms are always scalar because a Lagrangian is not allowed to be charged.