# Is spin-orbit coupling mass dependent?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, orbital-motion

When comparing spin-orbit coupling in the case of electrons and in the case of nucleons, do nuclear states exhibit a stronger level splitting compared to atomic states because the nucleons are more massive than the electrons (hypothetically considering all else equal)?

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling) notes the following but does not elaborate:

> In atomic nuclei, the spin–orbit interaction is much stronger than for
>   atomic electrons

If that is the case, why is it so?

Comment: I would guess that, rather than mass, it is stronger since the nucleons are much closer together than electrons. That would mean the electric field $\frac{\partial U}{ \partial r}$ term is much larger.

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288357/why-is-nuclear-force-spin-dependent/288499#288499