# Formulation of strong nuclear forces spin-dependent-term in larger nuclei

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

The nuclear force spin dependence term of deuterium is easy to explain, its was explained before in this site in question [288357](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288357/2451). But what about larger nuclei with higher mass numbers other than 2?

The main point of my question: Can spin term in nuclear force vary with nuclear mass number?