# Why spin-aligned nucleons bind stronger together

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, neutrons, protons, strong-force

Protons bind to neutrons only if their spin is parallel to each other. Is there an easy explanation for this? What force is responsable for this spin dependence?

Comment: [Strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is nuclear force spin dependent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288357/why-is-nuclear-force-spin-dependent)