# How strong nuclear force become repulsive at distance less than 0.7fm? What is its mechanism?

Tags: nuclear-physics, standard-model, strong-force

I read many times that **strong force become repulsive at distance less than (0.7×10^-15 m) but no-one explains how? and what is its carrier particle? what is its mechanism?**
I searched for answers so hard but didn't find.
And please don't say pauli exclusion principal because it is clearly said in Wikipedia that "principle which states that two or more identical fermions (particles with half-integer spin) cannot occupy the same quantum state within a quantum system simultaneously." And "Particles with an integer spin, or bosons, are not subject to the Pauli exclusion principle" so answer transformation of attractive nature of strong force to repulsive. repulsive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do nucleons feel a repulsive force when less than 1 fm?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78078/) (and multiple linked questions)

Comment: Yeah but people answer using pauli exclusion principal, but it is clearly said that "nuclear force become repulsive" so it is not a property it's a force. But my question is how can strongest force changes its nature form attractive to repulsive? Just after crossing certain limit??

Comment: You are misrepresenting nuclear potentials. Pion exchange is attractive, but ω exchange is repulsive (like a vector photon repelling two electrons off each other), and it is shorter-ranged, since its mass is ~ 5 times that of the pion.  The minimum of the resulting potential is near the confinement radius of nucleons, which further moots the picture. But *stop* yapping about Pauli exclusion, for crying out loud!

Comment: You have to  keep clear the "strong nuclear force" from the quantum chromodynamic "strong force." The "strong nuclear force" is  a residual force , spilling over from the strong force that keeps hadrons (protons or neutrons in this case) as individual bound states. It is modeled with the exchange of mesons between protons and neutrons. The repulsion in the nucleus comes because of the positive charges of the protons which are repulsive. As I say in my answer in the duplicate "In general for high Z more than twice the number of neutrons

Comment: are needed to overcome the same charge repulsion from the protons and get a stable nucleus."   Also: "the Pauli exclusion principle invoked in connection to nucleons is in justifying why all the nucleons of a nucleus do not end up on one energy state, the lower one ( similar to why all the electrons in an atom do not end up in the lowest ground state), but fill up consecutive energy layers."

Answer (score 0):

The gauge boson (or "carrier particle") of the strong interaction is the gluon, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon

As for the coupling strengths at different interaction energies (i.e. length scales), you might find this article helpful, in particular the sections about asymptotic freedom and scaling: https://www.pnas.org/content/102/26/9099

Comment: The OP is asking about the repulsive core of nuclear potentials, distinctly *not* QCD!